# Integrate FosUserBundle and HWIOAuthBundle

Tags: facebook, symfony, fosuserbundle, hwioauthbundle

Implementing the installation and documentation in [Integrating with FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/4-integrating_fosub.md) and following comments and leads from [A way to integrate FosUserBundle and HWIOAuthBundle](https://gist.github.com/danvbe/4476697)

Getting the correct code from Facebook connect API i am able to connect my Facebook account with the project, I can see the app added to my Facebook apps.
But now i want to fetch the user data from FB and store it in my database. I kind of understand what to do but the functions `public function connect(UserInterface $user, UserResponseInterface $response)` and `public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response)` are not being called after connecting with FB.
I am sure of that because i added non-existing methods in there just like getWhatever and setSomething even with syntax errors nothing happened and no logs are logged which means for 100% this class is never called.
How to fix this issue ?
Following is the files edited as in the examples.
Thanks in advance.

## MyFOSUBUserProvider.php

```
namespace MarketplaceBundle\Security\Core\User;

use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\Response\UserResponseInterface;
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider as BaseFOSUBProvider;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class MyFOSUBUserProvider extends BaseFOSUBProvider
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function connect(UserInterface $user, UserResponseInterface $response)
    {
        // get property from provider configuration by provider name
        // , it will return `facebook_id` in that case (see service definition below)
        $property = $this->getProperty($response);
        $username = $response->getUsername(); // get the unique user identifier

        //we "disconnect" previously connected users
        $existingUser = $this->userManager->findUserBy(array($property => $email));
        if (null !== $existingUser) {
            // set current user id and token to null for disconnect
            // ...

            $this->userManager->updateUser($existingUser);
        }
        // we connect current user, set current user id and token
        // ...
        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $userEmail = $response->getEmail();
        $user = $this->userManager->findUserByEmail($userEmail);

        // if null just create new user and set it properties
        if (null === $user) {
            $username = $response->getRealName();
            $user = new User();
            $user->setFirstName($response->getFirstName());
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
            // ... save user to database

            return $user;
        }else{
            $username = $response->getYamen();
            $user = new User();
            $user->setUsername($username);
        }
        // else update access token of existing user
        $serviceName = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();
        $setter = 'set' . ucfirst($serviceName) . 'AccessToken';
        $user->$setter($response->getAccessToken());//update access token

        return $user;
    }
}
```

## security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        ...
        secured_area:
            pattern: ^/
            oauth:
                resource_owners:
                    facebook:      /login_facebook
                login_path:        /login
                failure_path:      /login
                oauth_user_provider:
                    service: my_user_provider

            # Turn on anonymous for testings need.
            anonymous: ~

    access_control:
        ...
```

## config.yml

```
...
hwi_oauth:
    connect:
        account_connector: my_user_provider
    firewall_names:        [secured_area]
    fosub:
        username_iterations: 30
        properties:
            facebook:    facebook_id
    resource_owners:
        facebook:
            type:          facebook
            client_id:     'id'
            client_secret: 'secret'
            scope:         "email,public_profile,user_friends,user_birthday,user_location"
            options:
                display: popup
```

## services.yml

```
parameters:
    ...
    my_user_provider.class: MarketplaceBundle\Security\Core\User\MyFOSUBUserProvider

services:
    ...
    hwi_oauth.user.provider.entity:
        class: HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\OAuthUserProvider
    my_user_provider:
        class:        "%my_user_provider.class%"
        arguments: ['@fos_user.user_manager', { facebook: facebook_id }]

#routing.yml
hwi_oauth_redirect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
    prefix:   /facebook/connect

facebook_login:
    path: /login_facebook
...
```

## facebookJsCallFunction

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                    // init the FB JS SDK
                    FB.init({
                        appId      : 'id',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
                        status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
                        xfbml      : true,                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
                        version    : 'v2.5'
                    });
                };

                // Load the SDK asynchronously
                (function(d, s, id){
                    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

                function fb_login() {
                    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                        if (response.status === 'connected') {
                            // connected
                            alert('Already connected, redirect to login page to create token.');
                            console.log(response);
                            document.location = "{{ url("account") }}";
                        } else {
                            // not_authorized
                            FB.login(function(response) {
                                if (response.authResponse) {
                                    document.location = "{{ url("account") }}";
                                } else {
                                    alert('Cancelled.');
                                }
                            }, {scope: 'email,public_profile,user_friends,user_birthday,user_location'});
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my own solution :

```
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            oauth:
                oauth_user_provider:
#                    service: hwi_oauth.user.provider.fosub_bridge
                    service: acme.user_provider
```

Even if i get a "User account is disabled." error message on my FB test App test User